# How to sync new rabbitmq nodes with a current cluser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, load-balancing, autoscaling

Currently there is a cluster of 3 rabbitmq nodes, with each one in a different aws zones than any of the others. I have been able to cluster them and prove that is working.

The challenge I am running into is using autoscaling and automatically connecting new nodes to the cluster. From what I understand all of the other nodes must know about each other and have the other's IP's in their /etc/hosts file.

Is there a way to just search for the cluster name and tell the nodes to connect?

I have tried setting nodes behind ELBs and pointing them to the ELBs instead of IP's; however, that did not to work.

Comment: Your aim is easier if you use amazon VPC, and I think is more correct because you can reduce the TCP open ports and your RMQ instances are more protected.

In your case you could considerer to use amazon SQS to broadcast the new ip to the other servers and then change the host files.

Comment: @Gas That seems a little silly, basically using amazons mq to send a message to our mq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone else who is trying this the work around I did was to instal [aws-cli](http://alestic.com/2013/08/awscli). After doing that I wrote a script to change the /etc/hosts file based on the three different elb's I had (one for each node)

The script first finds that the ec2 instance behind the elb by running this command

`aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name <NAME OF YOUR ELB>`

The script then gets the ip of the ec2 behind the elb by running this command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <THE VALUE RETURNED FROM ABOVE> --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress' --output text
```

The trick that we are doing is running this in a script where it goes over each elb individually and there is only one elb infront of each node. This allows for a node to go down, be autoscalled back up and us to know the new ip without having to worry about manually edditing the file.

Thus we are just running over each one and telling it to save the output to the /etc/hosts file.

Hope that helps someone